# Will Paginate button not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

which is best gem package for pagination. I am using will_paginate buts its previous and next button are not working. Do you have any idea about it ??

```
    def client_info   
    sleep 2
    @clinet = BuyerInfo.paginate(page: params[:all], per_page: 2).order("id")
    #@clinet = BuyerInfo.all   
  end
```

Comment: What is your view code? Try changing this line BuyerInfo.paginate(page: params[:all], per_page: 2).order("id")  to BuyerInfo.order("id").paginate(page: params[:all], per_page: 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) but your current implementation might be wrong.

You should use page: params[:page] or whatever "field" of your params that you have explicitly declared in the will_paginate call in your view.

What does params[:all] keep as a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [will_paginage-bootstrap](https://github.com/nickpad/will_paginate-bootstrap) with the will-paginate gem for proper bootstrap layout.